# Resource unavailable when piping subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I am trying to find the path to the MATLAB executable using Python when it is not in PATH. I am using subprocess.Popen to execute locate and grepping the result, however this creates a Resource Unavailable error:

```
locate = subprocess.Popen(['locate', 'matlab'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '/bin/matlab$'], stdin=locate.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result, err = grep.communicate()
MATLAB_PATH = result.decode('UTF-8').split()
```

The *result* variable is empty and *err* variable is :

```
b'grep: (standard input): Resource temporarily unavailable\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code on linux with python 3.5.2 and 3.6.1 and it does work:

```
locate = subprocess.Popen(['locate', 'find'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '/bin/find$'], stdin=locate.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
grep.communicate()
(b'/usr/bin/find\n', b'')
```

For the records: `locate find` gives 1619 lines.
For completeness I have also tried `locate fdafad` (gibberish) and it also works.

It does also work when the code is in a script.

**edit:**

Try to use communicate to interact between to two processess:

```
locate = subprocess.Popen(['locate', 'find'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = locate.communicate()
grep = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '/bin/find$'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(grep.communicate(input=stdout))
```

---

**NOTE**: the second part of the answer has been written *before* the asker updated the question with information about the `PATH`

However there is a much better ways to find executables using python:

```
from distutils.spawn import find_executable
find_executable('find')

'/usr/bin/find'
```

If you insist in using shell functions, why don't use something like `which`.

Comment: My original code works for me too in the interpreter but not when I run it in a script. 

I am using Python3.6.1 and I can't use which  or find_executable because I do not know if the executable will be in the path of the machine/user running the code.

Comment: I see. Thank you for updating the question. I have tested again with python 3.6.1 and it does work there too.

Comment: Thank you for testing it. Do you have any idea why I might be getting this error? I am running the file using pytest, if that is relevant. There is also an exception that is produced:
Exception ignored in: <bound method Popen.__del__ of <eventlet.green.subprocess.Popen object at 0x104093cf8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 760, in __del__
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'warn'

Comment: I did search your error on google and gave a quick read to the results. I think that it can be due to locate generating too much output. Some of the older subprocess interface had [warnings about this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

Comment: @Haris: I have tried to add a communication between the two Popen. If the problem was due stdin/stdout lock this might work. The modified version also works on my computer, however I have no way to test if it fix your issue.

Comment: Yes! perfect that worked! Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: I have but I think because I have low reputation it doesn't have impact at the moment :(

Comment: I think that you upvoted me, instead of accepting the answer. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding just a little bit more information on why this error occurred.

This looks to be a problem with `eventlet` using "green" threads and non-blocking IO and locate **not** generating output fast enough. That is, eventlet assumes that the stdout is to be used by python. Eventlet uses non-blocking IO to assist in cooperative threading. This means the file descriptor behind `locate.stdout` that you pass to `grep` has already been set to non-blocking. If `grep` tries to read from stdin when it is empty then you will get that error.

An easy solution would be to do both commands in a single shell (so Python doesn't get to mess with the pipe between the two sub-processes).

eg.

```
result = subprocess.check_output('locate matlab | grep /bin/matlab$', shell=True).strip()
```